# Perform continuous mouse hover with Canvas?

Tags: selenium

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKOOF.png]I have to click one of options from left widget (See the Image1.PNG) will display single row as shown in ( See the [https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBNTN.png]Image.PNG) and then mousehover on each and every value and have to capture the tooltip for each values of that particular row.. 
xpath for the left and right widgets are:

```
@FindBy(xpath="//*[@id='tabZoneId21']/div/div/div/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/canvas")
    WebElement wbcanvasWidgetLeft; 

@FindBy(xpath="//*[@id=\"view5159778620503418402_17231458509407196328\"]/div[1]/div[2]/canvas[2]")
    WebElement wbcanvasWidgetRight;
```

And when I mouse hover on each and every value the following code gets highlights and  only the value of ‘left’ gets change otherwise its static for all options.

```
[![<div class = “ tab-tooltip tab-widget tab-tooltipAR”  style=”user-select: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; top: 1px; **left:119px**;”>… </div>
<div class=”tab-tooltipContainer”>
<div class =”tab-tooltipContent” wairole=”alert” style>
<div class=”tab-ubertip tab-widget” style=”min-width: 368px;”>.
<div class =”tab-ubertipContent”>
<div class=”tab-ubertipTooltip”>
<span style =”white-space:pre-wrap;tab-size:10;-moz-tab-size:10”>
<div style=”text-align:left;”>
                    <span style=””>Health Group </span>
</div>
<table style=”vertical-align:top;padding:0px” cellspacing=”0”>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style =”white-space:pre”>
    span style=”font-family”     >97</span>
</td>
<td >
    <span style=”font-”  >Minimum</span>
</td>][1]][1]
```

Only the value of  ‘left’ gets change for each options with some specific margin.

I have tried with following code which mousehover either 87.7% or 30.2% and displays the tooltip. I am not able mousehover on the first option that is 19.9% and so on in continuous manner.

```
public void sikuli() throws FindFailed, Exception {

 driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[title='data visualization']")));

        try{
        //Captured image of first option(Health) and clicked on in it       
     Screen s = new Screen();

                 Pattern target = new Pattern("Health.PNG");
                 s.wait(target,20);
                 s.mouseMove(target);
                 s.click();

Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    act.moveToElement(wbcanvasWidgetLeft).moveByOffset(-50,0).moveToElement(wbcanvasWidgetRight).build().perform();
    //Capturing Tooltip
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='tab-ubertipTooltip']/span/div[3]/span[1]")).getText());
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='tab-ubertipTooltip']/span/div[4]/span")).getText());

      }
         catch(Exception e)
            {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }

          driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    }
```

Can I use javascript executor with help of style attribute where I set the margin values for ‘left’ but i don't know how to set margin for style attribute while writing xpath.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to include an image (you mentioned Image1.PNG, but there's no image in the question).

Comment: Thanks, I have just added.

Comment: not sure I completely understand, but it seems like you could use an xpath that targets "//div[contains(@style, "left: specific px value")", then hover on that element. (maybe also include a check for class containing "tab-tooltipAR")