# When trying to verify whether the file has been downloaded or not getting an error null pointer exception

Tags: selenium

Please see the given image [https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoiQE.png] as individually downloading each file successfully with following code:

```
buttonDownload.click();  //This is the code just to download 'Image' option.
selectImageOption.click();
Thread.sleep(2300);
selectImageOptionToDownload.click();
```

To verify whether the image has been successfully downloaded or not? Tried 2 different ways but in both the case giving an error 'Null Pointer Exception'.

```
public  void isFileDownloaded() {
File downloadFolder = new File("C:\\Users\\dp\\Download"); //Path of default 'Download' folder. 
    List<String> namesOfFiles = Arrays.asList(downloadFolder.list()); //At this line getting an error "Null Pointer Exception"
    {
    if(namesOfFiles.contains("CM Supervisor Dashboard.png"))
    {   System.out.println("Downloaded");}
    else
        System.out.println("not downloaded");
       }
    }
```

Another logic i tried is:

```
public  boolean isFileDownloaded(String DownloadPath, String fileName) {
             boolean flag = false;
                File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\dp\\Download");
                File[] dir_contents = dir.listFiles();

                for (int i = 0; i < dir_contents.length; i++) {  //At this line getting an error 'Null Pointer Exception"
                    if (dir_contents[i].getName().equals("Dashboard"))
                        return flag=true;
                        }

                return flag;
            }
```

Comment: Seems like list() and listFiles() is returning null... check path? ("Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs."): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list()  Try/catch to see if i/o is thrown.

Comment: Use while loop and try-except to check if download successfully in x seconds or not (>x sec, raise error.)

Comment: @pcalkins, your link helped me. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Yun, your suggestion try-catch block has helped me out for the solution. Thank you so much.

Comment: Below code has worked for me, will help others.                                                      
 public void isFileDownloaded() {
   try {
    File f = new File("C:\\Users\\dp\\Downloads");
    FileFilter filter = new FileFilter() 
    {
     public boolean accept(File f)
     {     
      return f.getName().startsWith("CM");
     }};
    File[] files = f.listFiles(filter);
    System.out.println("Files are:");
    for (int i=0; i < files.length; i++) {
     System.out.println(files[i].getName()); }
   }catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());}
   }

Comment: Please check my question and help if any idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59720961/perform-continuous-mouse-hover-with-canvas?noredirect=1#comment105593643_59720961.

Comment: Before try block I have added few lines to download at specific location but it did not worked for me.  public void isFileDownloaded(){
 String downloadFilepath = "C:\\Users\\dp\\Desktop\\Download";
 HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
 chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
 options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);As my code downloading different extension files.

Comment: try with: String downloadFilepath = "C\:\\Users\\dp\\Desktop\\Download";

Comment: @pcalkins, Tried with: public void isFileDownloaded() throws IOException {
   String downloadFilepath ="C:\\Users\\dp\\Desktop\\Download" ;
  // File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\dp\\Downloads");
   File dir = new File(downloadFilepath);
   String[] extensions = new String[] { "png", "csv", "pdf", "pptx" };
   System.out.println("Getting all Downloaded files in " + dir.getCanonicalPath()
     + " with its path");
   List<File> files = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(dir, extensions, true);
   for (File file : files) {
    System.out.println("file: " + file.getCanonicalPath());
   } }}

Comment: But above code did not work for me.

Comment: sry, I think you may need to get rid of the escape chars... so try with "C:\Users\dp\Desktop\Download"

Comment: Tried with 'C:\Users\dp\Desktop\Download' did not work.

Comment: wait I thought you were trying to set chromedriver's download dir... so for chromedriver preferences you do not escape.  For setting a new File in Java, use "System.getProperty("user.dir");" and "System.getProperty("file.separator")".  That way it's platform dependent and you don't have to remember when to escape.  (btw, the escaped colon is only needed for properties files, so sorry for the false lead there)

Comment: System.getProperty, we used when created a folder under project, but how do i tell to download a files at specific location?

Comment: This is my code, if you can suggest something into itpublic void isFileDownloaded() {   
   
   try {
    File f = new File("C:\\Users\\pdholakia\\Downloads");
    
    FileFilter filter = new FileFilter() 
    {
     public boolean accept(File f)
     {
      return f.getName().startsWith("C");
     }};
    File[] files = f.listFiles(filter);

    for (int i=0; i < files.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(files[i].getCanonicalPath());}
   }catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
   } }. I have question too, how do i use assertion in above code?

Comment: The idea is that the exception will give you a clue as to why the code is not working.  Are you seeing an exception here?  Btw, you'll have to wait for the download to start which means polling for filecount before and after click... you should post a new question with code trials and exceptions thrown, if any.

Comment: It does not throw any exception, Its working fine now. Thank you so much.